# Lebesgue integrablity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

For which $a$ and $b$ is the following function $f(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$ in $L^1$

$f(x) = x^{-a}|\log x|^b$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are your ideas on the question?

Comment: change of variables for log x but got confused in parts between 1 to infinity and 0 to 1...

Comment: That's definitely the right track.  What did you get when you did that substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you tried to change the variable. So let's start with that and set $u:=\ln x$, $dx=e^udu$. Then the question becomes: is the following
$$
f(u)=e^{-au}|u|^be^u=e^{(1-a)u}|u|^b
$$
integrable over $\mathbb{R}$?

1) If $1-a>0$, then $\lim_{+\infty}f(u)=+\infty$. The integral diverges.

2) If $1-a<0$, then $\lim_{-\infty}f(u)=+\infty$. Divergence again.

3) If $1-a=0$, then $f(u)=|u|^b$. Recall (or prove, we have an easy antiderivative) that 
$$
\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{v^\alpha}<\infty\quad\iff\quad \alpha>1.
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{v^\beta}<\infty\quad\iff\quad \beta<1.
$$
So if we want our integral to converge, we need simultaneously $-b>1$ and $-b<1$. Impossible.

Conclusion: such functions are never integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $x^{-a}|\ln x|^b$ is never integrable over $(0,+\infty)$.